# Matching a C++ style regex with sed?

Tags: sed

Does anyone know how to match this C++ style regex using sed?  Specifically to break it into multiple parts using (pattern) and \n?

```
// ZIP code pattern: XXddddd-dddd and variants
regex pat (R"(\w{2}\s*\d{5}(−\d{4})?)");
```

For instance the following string would match AB00000-0000 and \1, \2, \3 would print appropriate substrings from pattern space.

SOLUTION:
Here is the sed answer, which accounts for initial two characters.

```
$ echo AB00000-0000 | sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\{2\}\)[[:space:]]*\([[:digit:]]\{5\}\)\(-\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)\)\{0,1\}/\1 \2 \4/' 
AB 00000 0000
```

Thank you

Comment: Please share input data and expected output. you can use ` -E, -r` option for extended regular expressions

Comment: The regexp pattern you show us begins with `\w{2}`, and that is mandatory, not optional. Your example string, 00000-0000, will **not** match the pattern.

Comment: Other than that, `\d` is a perl extension, recognized by `grep` (with the `P` flag) but not by `sed` or `awk`; you must use `[[:digit:]]` instead. And in order to be able to reference `[[:digit:]]{5}` in the replacement part, via backreference, you must enclose it in parentheses in the regular expression. That's pretty much it.

Comment: @mathguy you're correct.  I updated that match per your comment.

Comment: `\w` is not equivalent to `[[:alpha:]]`, it's equivalent to `[[:alnum:]_]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
\w{2}\s*\d{5}(−\d{4})?
```

is a PCRE (as would work in `perl` or GNU `grep -P` and can be written as a POSIX ERE (as would work in `awk` or `grep -E` or GNU/OSX `sed -E`) as:

```
[[:alnum:]_]{2}[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]{5}(−[[:digit:]]{4})?
```

or in a POSIX BRE (as would work in `grep` or `sed` without `-E`) as:

```
[[:alnum:]_]\{2\}[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]\{5\}\(−[[:digit:]]\{4\}\)\{0,1\}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file which contains:

```
NJ 08542-0033
PA19103-0200
NY10002
```

Then the `sed` command:

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]\{2\}[[:space:]]*\([[:digit:]]\{5\}\)\(-\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)\)\{0,1\}/\1 \3/' file
```

will output:

```
08542 0033
19103 0200
10002
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add that the initial two characters should be in the input.

Comment: @notaorb thank you for the feedback. Let me clarify your requirements. Do you want to print the first two characters in the output as well?